# Cómo cargar formularios dentro de una plantilla

Tags: php, codeigniter, mvc

Saludos, es mi primera pregunta y apenas estoy empezando a utilizar plantillas y el framework codeigniter, mi duda es la siguiente:

En la imagen de ayuda, a la izquierda donde dice formulario 1, qué debo hacer para que a la derecha en el Dashboard me cargue dicho formulario o vista, he intentado con algunos tutoriales pero no han sido claros. De antemano, gracias por la colaboración.

Tengo una vista principal que se llama página de prueba, en la cual tengo el siguiente código:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> Página de prueba </title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Página 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Página 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Página 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Página 4</a></li>
    </div>

    <div id="main-content">
        <?php $this->load->view($contenido); ?>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
        Elementos de footer
    </div>
</body>
```

En el controlador de dicha vista, lo siguiente:

```
$datos = array('contenido'=>'pagina1');
$this->load->view('pagina_prueba',$datos);
```

Mi pregunta concreta es: cómo desde los links de la vista principal, puedo cargar en la variable 'contenido' el nombre de las páginas respectivas, es decir...que al dar click en 'Página 2', el array $datos quede ('contenido' => 'pagina2')

[image: Imagen de ayuda]

Comment: No te serviría pasando como parámetro de la url el nombre del formulario al controlador?

Answer (score 0):

Sería algo poco estético pero creo más o menos así.

```html
<ul class="sidebar-menu">
        <li class="header">MENU</li>
        <li class="treeview">
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i> <span>ejemplo</span>
            <span class="pull-right-container">
              <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
            </span>
          </a>
          <ul class="treeview-menu">
            <li><a href="<?=base_url(); ?>Pagina1/<?='pagina1'?>">Pagina1</a></li>
            <li><a href="<?=base_url(); ?>Pagina2/<?='pagina2'?>">Pagina2</a></li>
            <li><a href="<?=base_url(); ?>pagina3/<?='pagina3'?>">Pagina3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
```

```
$route['Pagina1'] = 'Main/ejemploPagina1';
```

Main es el nombre del archivo del controlador.

En el controlador hice esta función:

```
public function ejemploPagina1($pagina)
{
    $data = array('contenido' => $pagina); 

    $this->load->view('pagina_prueba', $data);
}
```

Sino no te funciona mira en la ruta el paso de argumentos.